# Android check internet connection is working not just showing connected?

Tags: java, android, internet-connection

Hi I know how to check the internet connection available or not by referring to official site link :
https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html#DetermineType

But I need to find if the given internet connection is actually capable of loading www.google.com or any web site.

Let me explain the scenario, I do have wifi router named "Wifi-X" I am able to connect to this router but unable to load the web page www.google.com or any other site.

Now method explained on the official developer site (above link) shows connected even if I am just connected to router unable to ping the websites over the web.

So is there any solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

To check weather you can actually connect to the internet, you might want to try something as such:

```
public static boolean isInternetReachable() {
    InetAddress inet;
    try {
        inet = InetAddress.getByName("www.google.com");
        return true;
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Do remember that this cannot run on your main thread.